# error in xml sitemap

Tags: php, html, xml

i have problem in my website as i can't generate sitemap form site https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ , every time i generate it get empty sitemap with this comment

```
" This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."
```

and i really don't know how can i solve it

so please could anyone help me in this problem

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error. That's absolutely as expected. Sitemaps aren't for you to look at, they are designed for a machine to process.
[Reference](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=503258.0)

Answer (score 0):

XML and HTML are like cousins. They share a lot of it's syntaxis, but html has some standardized semantics, while the semantics of xml is totally up to you, the creator of a xml document.

So what happens here; you're browser is reading xml, but a *tag* is *not* considered something to be outputted, it is considered to be *describing* something, which can be outputted on a certain way, if there is styling information available.

So what you see is the browser (<sub>probably IE; get a proper browser</sub>) telling you it doesn't know how to present the xml file in a proper way and deciding it will not show it at all. But if you look to the source (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>), your sitemap will be there.

Although in contrast to what @ShakirKhan says; xml is designed to be looked at *both* by humans as well as computers. So it is understandable, but it should not happen. You should just see the xml file (<sub>so, get a proper browser</sub>)